# Exception when using sshexec in ant 1.10

Tags: jenkins, build, ant

I'm trying deploy a PHP application using Ant script.  I've put all the necessary jars in the library: ie ant-jsch-1.8.1.jar, jsch-0.1.55.jar

In my script i declare the sshexec and scp as followed:

```
<path id="jsch.class.path">
      <pathelement location="lib/ant-jsch-1.8.1.jar" />
      <pathelement location="lib/jsch-0.1.55.jar" />
    </path>
    <taskdef name="scp" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp" classpathref="jsch.class.path" />
    <taskdef name="sshexec" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec" classpathref="jsch.class.path" />
```

When the build is executed in Jenkins i get these errors event though the location of the public key is correct:

```
[sshexec] Caught exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa   (No such file or directory)

[sshexec] Caught exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa   (No such file or directory)

[scp] Caught exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa   (No such file or directory)
```

The weird thing is when i run the build script locally on my machine it works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use a master or a different node to run that? If you use the different one, where are your ssh files stored, on the node, or on the master?

Comment: biruk1230 what do you mean by 'use a master or different node'?  I run the script on a jenkins server and it has all the required library files.  Also the compiled files are in the same workspace.

Comment: I mean that often Jenkins server (aka 'master') has also few additional nodes to run projects. And often the problem is that your file is located on master, but you run the job on a different node. From your answer I suppose that you have only one Jenkins master without additional nodes, so I can only propose to double-check the name of the file in your directory, maybe you have `id_dsa.pub` or `id_rsa` instead of `id_dsa` file in `/home/jenkins/.ssh` directory.

Comment: thanks..i did have a typo, it should have been id_rsa.  Unfortunately it still had the same error except this time the file name is 'id_rsa'.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're trying to provide `id_rsa` but in that directory have `id_rsa.pub` file, not just `id_rsa`?

Comment: I found that the public key is actually a dsa key, so it was correctly set for id_isa initially.  Basically i'm back to square 1 :(

Comment: You actually talking about public key (which should be `id_dsa.pub`), but error shows that you have not found private key (which should be `id_dsa`, without `.pub` extension). Maybe you just trying to specify your private key instead of public one (or vice versa)?

Comment: I finally figured out the issue.  I have a variable that holds that path to the private key but the string had an extra space or character and ant got confused.  I replaced the variable and put the path in directly and it works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lesson learned: if something fails and nothing else seem to work..go back to the basics..try direct path and no variables or aliases ;)

Comment: Yes, that's right :)
Also, please add an answer to your question with specifying the solution, maybe it can help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had a variable that holds the path to the private key, the string probably had an extra space or character and ANT got confused. I replaced variable with the direct path of the private key and it worked.  To reuse the variable I copied the path and assigned it to the same variable in run command.